# Java наследование, методы

Tags: java, ооп, классы, наследование

Мучаюсь весь вечер, не могу реализовать пару моментов.
Разработать приложение для вычисления результирующей информации об объектах, описанных с помощью наследования:
•   Базовый класс «Рабочий» (Worker). Класс имеет следующие поля: имя (name), возраст (age) и зарплата (salary) и методы: setName, getName, setAge, getAge, setSalary, getSalary.
•   Класс Worker1, производный от класса Worker имеет дополнительный метод checkAge, который будет проверять возраст на корректность (от 1 до 100 лет). Этот метод должен использовать метод setAge перед уста-новкой нового возраста (если возраст не корректный - он не должен ме-няться)
•   Класс Worker2, производный от класса Worker1, проверяет корректность зарплаты: положительное число, больше прожиточного минимума и меньше некоторого предельного числа.

1. Создать список работников на основе класса Worker2
2. Обеспечить возможность поиска в списке по различным полям (имя. возраст, диапазон зарплат)
   **Классы есть, Worker работает отлично, Searcher тоже, то есть, поиск в списке по полям реализован. Как сделать Worker1 с методом checkAge и Worker2 с проверкой на корректность? В java далеко не силен, поэтому проблема.**

**Worker.java**

```
package com.company;
public class Worker {
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public int salary;
//    private final String name;
//    private final int age;
//    private final int salary;

    public Worker(String name, int age, int salary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Worker{" + "name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", salary=" + salary + "}\n";
    }

}
```

**WorkerSearcher.java**

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class WorkerSearcher {

    private String name;
    private Integer minAge;
    private Integer maxAge;
    private Integer minSalary;
    private Integer maxSalary;

    public WorkerSearcher setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public WorkerSearcher setMinAge(Integer minAge) {
        this.minAge = minAge;
        return this;
    }

    public WorkerSearcher setMaxAge(Integer maxAge) {
        this.maxAge = maxAge;
        return this;
    }

    public WorkerSearcher setMinSalary(Integer minSalary) {
        this.minSalary = minSalary;
        return this;
    }

    public WorkerSearcher setMaxSalary(Integer maxSalary) {
        this.maxSalary = maxSalary;
        return this;
    }
    public List<Worker> search(Collection<Worker> workers) {
        return workers.stream()
                .filter(worker->name == null || worker.getName().equals(name))
                .filter(worker->rangeOf(worker.getAge(), minAge, maxAge))
                .filter(worker->rangeOf(worker.getSalary(), minSalary, maxSalary))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private boolean rangeOf(Integer value, Integer min, Integer max) {
        if (min==null && max==null) return true;
        if (min!=null && max==null && min<=value) return true;
        if (max!=null && min==null && max>=value) return true;
        if (max!=null && min!=null && max>=value && min<=value) return true;
        return false;
    }

}
```

**Worker1.java**

```
package com.company;

public class Worker1 extends Worker {
    public Worker1(String name, int age, int salary) {
        super(name, age, salary);
    }
}
```

**Worker2.java**

```
package com.company;

public class Worker2 extends Worker1{
    public Worker2(String name, int age, int salary) {
        super(name, age, salary);
    }

    public void checkSalary(){
        if (salary > 0) {
            System.out.println("Зарплата " + name + " - положительное число");
        } else System.out.println("Зарплата " + name + "  - отрицательное число");
        if (salary > 12038) {
            System.out.println("Зарплата " + name + "  выше прожиточного минимума");
        } else System.out.println("Зарплата " + name + "  ниже прожиточного минимума");
            if (salary < 100000) {
            System.out.println("Зарплата " + name + "  ниже предельного числа");
        } else System.out.println("Зарплата " + name + "  выше предельнего числа");
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
package com.company;
import java.util.ArrayList;
//import java.util.Scanner;
//import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<>();

        workers.add(new Worker("Ivan", 25, 12000));
        workers.add(new Worker("Sergey", 22, 9800));
        workers.add(new Worker("Michael", 32, 123000));
        workers.add(new Worker("Vladislav", 45, 6500));
        workers.add(new Worker("Nikolay", 19, 12200));
        workers.add(new Worker("Valery", 37, 32500));

        List<Worker> result = new WorkerSearcher()
                .setMinSalary(9500)
                .setMaxSalary(33000)
                .setMaxAge(36)
                .search(workers);

        System.out.println(result);




    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае вы находитесь в заложниках у своего конструктора и финальных полей. Боюсь, что самый простой способ реализации - избавиться от указанных проблем, но придется немного переписать код. Во-первых, убираем модификатор final со всех полей и конструктор с параметрами. Во-вторых, для инициализации полей добавим сеттеры. При этом все сеттеры будут возвращать this, т.е. самого себя. В целом так делать нехорошо, но я боюсь, что вам не знаком паттерн билдер, а стандартные сеттеры усложнят инициализацию экземпляров класса worker. Ну и, собственно, все, теперь можно наследоваться и переопределять нужные нам сеттеры.

```
public class Worker {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int salary;
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public Worker setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public Worker setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
        return this;
    }

    public Worker setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
        return this;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Worker{" + "name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", salary=" + salary + '}';
    }
    
}

public class Worker1 extends Worker{
    
    @Override
    public Worker setAge(int age) {
        return age>0 && age<=100 ? super.setAge(age): this;
    }
    
}

public class Worker2 extends Worker{
    
    private final static int LIVING_WAGE = 12_038;
    
    private final static int SAKARY_LIMIT = 100_000;

    @Override
    public Worker setSalary(int salary) {
        return salary<LIVING_WAGE || salary>SAKARY_LIMIT ? this : super.setSalary(salary);
    }
    
}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        List<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<>();        
        workers.add(new Worker().setName("Ivan").setAge(25).setSalary(12000));
        workers.add(new Worker1().setName("Sergey").setAge(22).setSalary(9800));
        workers.add(new Worker2().setName("Artem").setAge(48).setSalary(54000));
        
        List<Worker> result = new WorkerSearcher()
                .setMinSalary(10000)
                .setMaxAge(40)
                .search(workers);
        
        System.out.println(result);
        
        System.out.println("*** TEST 'SET AGE'***");
        workers.get(1).setAge(105);
        System.out.println(workers);
        workers.get(1).setAge(23);
        System.out.println(workers);
        
        System.out.println("*** TEST 'SET SALARY'***");
        workers.get(2).setSalary(200_000);
        workers.get(2).setSalary(0);
        System.out.println(workers);
        workers.get(2).setSalary(55000);
        System.out.println(workers);
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Круто, спасибо огромное). Когда-нибудь я научусь, наверное, все это делать без проблем, но пока вот приходится постоянно обращаться за помощью.

Answer (score 0):

А мне кажется не нужно тут сильно заморачиваться, в плане, что сеттеры должны возвращать this.  Это дико странно. Каждый класс просто добавляет новый функционал. Вот просто берите и реализуйте в нужном классе нужные методы. А в классе Worker2  используйте весь функционал